# SearchView needs to be clicked twice to open

Tags: android, searchview

I'm following this [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/search/index.html) to implement the Search View. After fixing some issues, I got it to work. However, the search view needs to be clicked twice to open the editText. Any idea of what's going on?

**Filter** class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu_filter, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**menu**.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".FilterUI">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_options"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_clear_all_white"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/filter_default"/>
```

**Manifest** file

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.FilterUI"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activities.SearchActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: Why you don't use `SearchView` **v7**, more compatibility and easy to use: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html

Comment: Oh, it works fine now, thanks!

Comment: Note to self, ignore this completely: "Note: This class is included in the support library for compatibility with API level 7 and higher. If you're developing your app for API level 11 and higher only, you should instead use the framework SearchView class." Support V7 is the way to go regardless

Comment: Probably wasn't using v7 because developer docs https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup don't use it.
You should use v7 as @Mohsen said

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Might be too late to answer but, let's get this done. Like I said, it's better to use:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

For more compatibility and etc. But the point is, in new `AndroidX`, we can't use `android.support` since we migrate to `AndroidX` and there will be only:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

Available. But, let's see what documentation says for the newest APIs (AndroidX) and etc:

> **Note:** [This class](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/SearchView) is included **in the support library** for compatibility *with API level 7 and higher*. If you're developing your
>   app for *API level 11 and higher only*, you should instead use the
>   framework `android.widget.SearchView` class.

So in `AndroidX`, I have found:

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

To use but you still can use: `android.widget.SearchView`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, replacing from app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"  to app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" works for me.